# Concatenating ActiveRecord::Relations queried through polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My application has a Job model. Every job in the system has a `contact`. This is like a person you would call up if you need to ask a question about the job. A contact can either be a `client` or an employee of a client (`ClientEmployee`).

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact, polymorphic: true
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs, as: :contact
  has_many :employees, class_name: 'ClientEmployee'
end

class ClientEmployee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  has_many :jobs, as: :contact
end
```

Clients have the idea of `commissioned_jobs`. The clients commissioned jobs are those jobs for which the client is the contact OR one of the client's employees is the contact.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs, as: :contact
  has_many :employee_jobs, through: :employees, source: :jobs

  def commissioned_jobs
    jobs << employee_jobs
  end
end
```

Aside: That method is a bit of a hack because it returns an array rather than an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. It's also interesting that it blows up if I try to concat jobs into employee_jobs. It may or may not do for my purposes.

I would like to add a scope to `Client` called `with_commissioned_jobs`. This should return all the clients in the system who have jobs or who have employees who have jobs.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.with_commissioned_jobs
    # I can get clients with jobs using: joins(:jobs). How do 
    # I also include clients with employees who have jobs?
  end
end
```

How do I implement this method?

I'm using Rails 3.2.9.

**Update:**

I've made some progress and I now have two methods, each of which does half of what I need.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Return all clients who have an employee with at least one job.
  def self.with_employee_jobs
    joins(employees: :jobs)
    # SQL: SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" INNER JOIN "client_employees" ON "client_employees"."employer_id" = "clients"."id" INNER JOIN "jobs" ON "jobs"."contact_id" = "client_employees"."id" AND "jobs"."contact_type" = 'ClientEmployee'
  end

  # Return all clients who have at least one job.
  def self.with_jobs
    joins(:jobs)
    # SQL: SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" INNER JOIN "jobs" ON "jobs"."contact_id" = "clients"."id" AND "jobs"."contact_type" = 'Client'
  end
end
```

Now all I need to do is combine these two method calls into one `ActiveRecord::Relation`. I can obviously do this:

```
  def self.with_commissioned_jobs
    with_jobs + with_employee_jobs
  end
```

The problem is that that returns an array rather than an instance of `Relation` and I can't chain more scopes on it.

**Update 2**:

Using `merge` doesn't appear to work either. Here is the AR query and the resulting SQL.

```
joins(:jobs).merge(joins(employees: :jobs))

SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" INNER JOIN "jobs" 
  ON "jobs"."contact_id" = "clients"."id" 
  AND "jobs"."contact_type" = 'Client' 
  INNER JOIN "client_employees" 
  ON "client_employees"."employer_id" = "clients"."id" 
  INNER JOIN "jobs" "jobs_client_employees" 
  ON "jobs_client_employees"."contact_id" = "client_employees"."id" 
  AND "jobs_client_employees"."contact_type" = 'ClientEmployee'
```

By the way, here are the tests I'm trying to pass. The first test fails because there are zero results when I use merge.

```
describe "with_commissioned_jobs" do
  # A client with a job.
  let!(:client_with) { create :client }
  let!(:job) { create :job, contact: client_with }
  # A client who does not himself have a job, but who has an employee
  # with a job.
  let!(:client_with_emp) { create :client }
  let!(:employee) { create :client_employee, employer: client_with_emp }
  let!(:emp_job) { create :job, contact: employee }
  # A client with nothing. Should not show up.
  let!(:client_without) { create :client }

  it "should return clients with jobs and clients with employee jobs" do
    Client.with_commissioned_jobs.should == [client_with, client_with_emp]
  end

  it "should return a relation" do
    Client.with_commissioned_jobs.should be_instance_of(ActiveRecord::Relation)
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you looked into arel? https://github.com/rails/arel  It has an or condition for queries, and handles complex joins well.

Comment: I will certainly accept an Arel based solution too. I've spent quite a few hours trying to come up with one and I don't seem to be able to manage it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered the gem [meta_where](https://github.com/ernie/meta_where)?  The main thing seems to be that you want to return an `ActiveRecord:Relation` object for further chaining.

**UPDATE 2**: got it working with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` jobs twice with aliasing

```
  # scope for ::Client
  def self.with_commissioned_jobs
    self.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN client_employees ON clients.id =client_employees.client_id").
        joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN jobs AS cjobs ON clients.id = cjobs.contact_id AND cjobs.contact_type = 'Client'").
        joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN jobs AS ejobs ON client_employees.id = ejobs.contact_id AND ejobs.contact_type = 'ClientEmployee'").
        where("cjobs.id IS NOT NULL OR ejobs.id IS NOT NULL")
  end
```

Seeing if it works:

```
    #c1 has no job
    c1 = Client.create

    #c2 has a job
    c2 = Client.create
    c2.jobs.create

    #c3 has no job, but has an employee with a job
    c3 = Client.create
    c3.employees.create
    c3.employees.first.jobs.create

    puts Client.all.inspect             #=> [#<Client id: 1>, #<Client id: 2>, #<Client id: 3>] 
    puts Client.with_commissioned_jobs  #=> [#<Client id: 2>, #<Client id: 3>]

    puts [c2,c3] == Client.with_commissioned_jobs.all    #=> true
```

Comment: Doesn't support Rails 3.2 I'm afraid. I have tried [Squeel](https://github.com/ernie/squeel) which is similar to MetaWhere but I can't seem to get it to merge `AR::Relation`'s.

Comment: Your update works with one slight modification which is needed because my client employees foreign key is `employer_id` as opposed to `client_id`. Great work, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 joins( :jobs, {employees: :jobs} )
```

It should join client's jobs as well as client employees' jobs. See [the guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-array-hash-of-named-associations) for a more thorough information.

**Edit**

In your case, you may use `Relation.merge` :

```
 joins( :jobs ).merge( joins(employees: :jobs) )
```

Comment: I'm reading the guides (thanks for the link btw) and as far as I can understand the code you provided should return "customers who have jobs AND have employees who have jobs". Really I'm looking for an OR condition and I don't see a way to do that.

Comment: Merge doesn't appear to work either I'm afraid. I appended more information to the question along with the specs I'm working with.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an important reason to stick with polymorphism?

If a ClientEmployee always has a Client, maybe you should have `Job.belongs_to :client`. This makes your relation dead simple. I have found adding some redundant associations can be great performance optimizations as well, as long as it doesn't make it more difficult to keep your records coherent (i.e. Client/ClientEmployee relationships being in sync with Job.Client/Job.ClientEmployee assignments when both are present).

I really like polymorphism in rails but it can get tricky when you're trying to join across them as in this case. Even if you had separate Client and ClientEmployee id's, that would be more efficient in the db (two ints vs. int and string).

Comment: Good suggestion. The point of the current setup is that although only clients can be billed for job, in day-to-day management, an employee of a client could be the go-to-guy for the job, rather than the client themselves. What I will look into is having client_employees just be records in the client table and then using self-referencing within that table in order to simulate employment.

Comment: In this case `def Job.contact; client_employee || client; end` provides this will keeping your schema optimized for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs, as: :contact
  has_many :employees, class_name: 'ClientEmployee'

  scope :with_commissioned_jobs, lambda do
    includes(:jobs, {:employees => :jobs}).where("jobs.contact_type IS NOT NULL AND jobs.contact_id IS NOT NULL")
  end
end
```

Ok, my another decision from real working application. Old school help you. :)

This method just create arrayed condition for AR:Relation for polymorphic stuff.

```
module ActiveRecordHelper

  def self.polymorphic_sql(*args)
    conditions = []
    table = args.first.table_name
    stack = args.extract_options!
    sql_queries = stack.collect do |as_resource, hash|
      resource_queries = hash.collect do |name, find_options|
        resource_class = name.to_s.classify.constantize
        resource_table = resource_class.table_name
        conditions << resource_class.name
        if find_options[:conditions].present?
          conditions += find_options[:conditions][1..-1]
        end
        joins_clause =
        Array.wrap(find_options[:join]).collect do |association|
          reflection = resource_class.reflections[association]            
          if reflection.macro == :belongs_to && reflection.options[:polymorphic] != true
            "INNER JOIN #{reflection.klass.table_name} ON #{reflection.active_record.table_name}.#{reflection.foreign_key} = #{reflection.klass.table_name}.id"
          elsif reflection.macro.in?([:has_many, :has_one]) && reflection.options[:as].nil?
            "INNER JOIN #{reflection.klass.table_name} ON #{reflection.klass.table_name}.#{reflection.foreign_key} = #{reflection.active_record.table_name}.id"
          end
        end.compact.join(" ").strip
        "(#{table}.#{as_resource}_type = ? AND EXISTS(#{["SELECT 1 FROM #{resource_table}#{joins_clause.left_indent(1) if joins_clause.present?} WHERE #{resource_table}.id = #{table}.#{as_resource}_id", find_options[:conditions].first].compact.join(" AND ")}))"
      end
      "CASE WHEN #{table}.#{as_resource}_type IS NOT NULL AND #{table}.#{as_resource}_id IS NOT NULL THEN #{resource_queries.join(" OR ")} ELSE TRUE END"
    end
    conditions.insert(0, "(#{sql_queries.join(" OR ")})")
  end

end
```

Then extend your polymorphic Job:

```
def self.comissioned_by(client)
  conditions = ActiveRecordHelper.polymorphic_sql(self, :contact => {:client => {:conditions => ["clients.id = ?", client.id]}, :client_employee => {:conditions => ["client_employees.client_id = ?", client.id]}}
  where(conditions)
end
```

Now call:

```
Job.commissioned_by()  # pass client instance
```

Enjoy. If any details needed, type me.

Comment: This returns an empty relation when run on the tests I included in the question I'm afraid.

Comment: i just hate arel style syntax. )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do a custom join?

```
def self.with_commissioned_jobs
  query = <<-QUERY
    INNER JOIN client_employees 
    ON client_employees.employer_id = clients.id 
    INNER JOIN jobs 
    ON ((jobs.contact_id = client_employees.id AND jobs.contact_type = 'ClientEmployee') 
      OR (jobs.contact_id = clients.id AND jobs.contact_type = 'Client'))
  QUERY

  joins(query)
end
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to extract the client who is directly the contact of a job in the tests I included in my question. It only returns `client_with_emp`.